# Hibernate getOne() not working with background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

There is a scenario I have encountered, where I'm returning the API response(request thread) and delegating the task to a background thread.
In the background thread, I'm calling hibernate's `T getOne(ID id);` to fetch some information, which is resulting in

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session in Thread class

But, when performing DB operations with **JPA queries** `@Query("some query")`, **native query** `@Query(value = "some query", native = true)` and **JdbcTemplate**, it's working fine in the background thread.

Can someone help me understand why such behaviour?

FYI.. I'm using **Spring Boot 1.4.2** and **Hibernate 5.0.11**

Comment: Haven't checked but the same behavior might be observed with other default methods like List<T> findAll();

Comment: LazyInitializationException means you (hibernate) is trying to fetch things from the database when the active session is closed. Fix your query to get everything you need while in session. Also, hibernate binds to a specific thread so it might be bound to the initial thread and not the background thread.

Comment: ok. whenever an object is requested the session should be established/open again ? And why not the same scenario happening with JPAQL/HQL ?

Comment: Don't exactly know -- you said native queries so I suspect it's just going into JDBC at that point. Basically you will need to research Hibernate and background threads and I don't think you will turn up any easy answers. I remember working at it once for a while but I don't think I got to a good solution. Once hibernate starts latching on to threads it will be difficult to sort out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T getOne(ID id)` relies on `EntityManager.getReference()` that performs an entity lazy loading. So to ensure the effective loading of the entity, invoking a method on it is required.

Basically your thread is unable to find any active sessions `context.Hibernate` throws the `LazyInitializationException` when it needs to initialize a lazily fetched association to another entity without an active session context.
You `FetchType.EAGER` in any of the associations you are having w.r.t to the object you are trying to get. But, it can have its own repercussions like unwanted query execution every time you try to get object.

Best Solution will be using `Optional<T> findById(ID id)` You can get check if entity exists using `obj.isPresent()` and continue.